# Custom avatar image link added to the profile page

Tags: author, profiles, gravatar

I'm trying to create a custom author field, the user will past his profile image url. and replace his avatar which displayed in comments.

the field :

```
function custom_avatar_img($profile_fields) {
$profile_fields['thecustomavatar'] = __('Your Profile Image','mytheme');

    return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'custom_avatar_img');
```

to replace gravatar:

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'cyb_get_avatar', 10, 5 );
function cyb_get_avatar( $avatar = '', $id_or_email, $size = 96, $default = '', $alt = '' ) {
$avatar_img = get_the_author_meta('thecustomavatar');
    // Replace $avatar with your own image element, for example
     $avatar = "<img alt='$alt' src='".$avatar_img."' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";

    return $avatar;

}
```

it worked but it displaying only the author image in all comments even he isn't the comment poster.
I think get_the_author_meta('thecustomavatar') isn't the right way.
So, how to get the comment poster custom image field content ?!!!